# I noticed my thesis model is valid only for a specific case, and I've already submitted my thesis, what should I do?

Tags: thesis, masters, engineering, errors-erratum

I accidentally used settings that are not so common (for example, putting a real model of a system in space), and did the whole analysis on that setting. The analysis itself is correct on that model, it's just that you would have to apply certain conditions. I realized this issue after submitting my thesis, and my supervisor is currently on a vacation, so I cannot consult him. Will this make me fail my master thesis?

I have to mention that my supervisor checked my thesis several times, and this mistake was always present and he saw it, but probably overlooked it.

Comment: We don't know the requirements at your institution, so all we can say is: wait till your advisor is back from vacation.

Comment: If your advisor already read the thesis and gave his OK for submitting, it's unlikely that anything will happen. Did you specify the conditions in the thesis (that would be optimal, as it would dismantle any criticism from the beginning)?

Comment: I specified all of the conditions under which the experiments were done, that's how I noticed I made a mistake. I have one figure that clearly states that the model is positioned in some conditions that are not so likely (in my case, having a robot arm on a moving platform), and he saw it several times, but never asked me about it. He also saw my model before, I even asked him to check it one more time before I continue with other analysis. - @lighthouse keeper

Comment: Then it seems that the reporting is solid and you have nothing to be concerned about. Science proceeds in small steps, and you made one by performing a simulation under clearly specified and reported conditions.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It will keep me sane for a week until my advisor comes back.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper, probably an answer if not closed for being to "individual".

Comment: @Buffy Thanks! I posted a briefly expanded version of my comments as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to be worried at all:

- Pragmatically, if your advisor already read the thesis, gave his OK for submitting and did not even mention the issue, it's unlikely that he will change his mind.
- More fundamentally, science proceeds in small steps, and you made one by performing a simulation under clearly specified conditions that you adequately reported in the thesis.

For your thesis defense, you may want to prepare for a potential question about your motivation for choosing these particular conditions. But it's very unlikely that even a bad answer would lead to you failing the thesis.

Comment: And you have an obvious project for "future work".